# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on each and every page of website

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, redirect, https

I finally installed SSL on my website `www.giftdays.jp`. it works flawlessly.
It shows green padlock "secured" like I wished for.
But the problem is it only shows on main page. Whenever I access other page such as product page and all, green padlock is gone, and just shows exclamation inside circle. ( It doesn't show NOT SECURED WITH CROSSED HTTPS) . 
After opening inspects from chrome, I get MIXED CONTENT error .
This is the exact error.

"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.giftdays.jp/products/list.php?mode=search&sps=5' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.giftdays.jp/special/list_header/happywedding/images/happywedding.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."

Though my site is loaded on HTTPS , why isn't it showing green padlock?
By googling and all, I ended up in stack with someone posting some **htaccess** post which i added on my **htaccess** and uploaded on server. Code I added was :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Yet no changes on other pages of website.
This is what`s inside my **htaccess** file :

```
# 基本は SC_Initial.php で設定するが、ini_setで反映されないものはここで設定する

php_value mbstring.language Japanese
php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation off
php_value output_handler none
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag session.auto_start 0

# INI_ALL なのにもかかわらず, ini_set で指定しても反映されない環境がある...
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8

# デフォルトテンプレートの状態で 2M 近くになるため
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
#php_value post_max_size 8M
php_flag register_globals off

RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

###################
# メンテナンス中
###################
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/503.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Gds1q2w3eAdmin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user_data/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=114.179.83.200
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=54.250.233.6
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201403311500
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <201406011000
RewriteRule ^.*$ /503.php [L]

###################
# 通常使用
###################
RewriteRule ^guide/(.*)$ user_data/guide/$1
RewriteRule ^products/shop_map.php user_data/products/shop_map.php
RewriteRule ^concierge/.* user_data/concierge/$1
RewriteRule ^original/(.*)$ user_data/original_catalog/$1
RewriteRule ^gift/(.*)$ user_data/gift/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#商品ページのURL書き換え
RewriteRule ^gifts/([0-9]+)/$ products/detail.php?product_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gifts/([0-9]+)/shop_map.php user_data/products/shop_map.php

#カタログページのURL書き換え
RewriteRule ^catalog/price-([0-9]+)/$ user_data/catalog/list.php?catalog_type_id=1&catalog_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/theme-([0-9]+)/$ user_data/catalog/list.php?catalog_type_id=2&catalog_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ user_data/catalog/$1

#有効性テスト用
# Redirect /api/ http://www.google.com

#Pマーク指摘対応
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/contact/.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/entry/.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/gift/.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/mypage/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?giftdays.jp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# 404ページ
ErrorDocument 404 /user_data/404.php
```

Upon investigating more, I found some http inside my templates folder inside ftp. But they are like in many 100+ I guess.Should i go inside one by one and change all to https or is there anything I could do to change all at once?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When setting up Apache to send an http request to https, you can't use the rewrite engine. You have to use the Redirect directive.

Probably you already have two VirtualHost blocks setup for http and https. Any request arriving on the http VirtualHost should be redirected to the https URL.